# Dice Roll Probability

Tags: probability

I think I am just doing something really dumb but I am having a hard time with this problem. Consider that one is rolling $n$ six-sided dice. We wish to calculate the probability that at least $m$ of those dice show the same value when rolled. Here is my approach:

We clearly have that the total number of "configurations" that $n$ die can assume is $6^n$. How many ways can $m$ die show the same value? To my mind, it is,
\begin{align}
6 \times {n \choose m} \times 5^{n - m}.
\end{align}
To explain my reasoning, I claim that we choose $m$ of the $n$ die to show a particular value (hence the $n$-choose-$k$). There are six such values that may be shown (hence the factor of six). Finally, the remaining die (of which there are $n-m$) may show any of the five remaining values.

Since we are interested in the at least $m$ case, and since I have treated the problem generally above, I think I need only sum over the values greater than $m$ to obtain the total number of ways that $n$ die can show at least $m$ die of the same value. Thus, the probability I seek is,
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum_{i = m}^n 6\times {n\choose i} \times 5^{n-i}}{6^n}
\end{align}

To convince myself that this is correct, I considered the case where $n=4$ and $m = 3$. This yielded,
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum_{i = 3}^4 6\times {4\choose i} \times 5^{4-i}}{6^4} = \frac{7}{72}\approx 0.097
\end{align}
This agrees with simulation so I think I am on the right track. Consider instead the case $n=20$ and $m=5$. This apparently yields,
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum_{i = 5}^{20} 6\times {20\choose i} \times 5^{20-i}}{6^{20}}\approx 1.3875
\end{align}
A probability greater than one! Can someone help me find what I am doing wrong? The answer according to simulation should be approximately $0.9278$.

Thanks!

Comment: Double counting: in your last example we could have 5 ones and 5 twos and we'd count these configurations twice. $n=4, m= 3$ has no such possibilities.

Comment: Oh I understand. Is there a convenient way to deal with the overcounting problem? Or do you think double counting contributes too much complexity for a nice solution?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion could deal with it,  I think. But it gets messy for general $n,m$, I'd think.

Comment: Suppose $n=10$ and $m=5$.  Then the case of $m$ ones and $m$ twos could occur, and would get counted when you count the cases of $m$ ones, and would get counted again when you count the cases of $m$ twos. ${}\qquad{}$